# Tensorflow - equivalence of scipy.linalg.circulant

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking for the best way to do the equivalent to `scipy.linalg.circulant`

[scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html)

I can use `LinearOperatorCirculant` and then call `to_dense()` but the performance is horrible compared to `scipy.linalg.circulant` when the dimensions are large.

I can also use multiple `tf.stack` with `tf.roll` but there must be a better and faster way.

I couldn't find a way to integrate with `scipy.linalg.circulant` because I'm using this operation on `tf.Variable`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tf.scatter_nd instead of tf.roll, which requires knowing the static dimension of the matrix.

```
def circulant(elements):
    elements = tf.convert_to_tensor(elements)
    dim = tf.size(elements)
    range_t = tf.range(dim)    
    tiled = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.reshape(elements, [-1, 1]), [1, dim]), [-1])
    row_indices = tf.tile(range_t, [dim])
    col_indices = tf.mod(tf.reshape(tf.reshape(range_t, [-1, 1]) + tf.reshape(
        range_t, [1, -1]), [-1]), dim)
    indices = tf.stack([row_indices, col_indices], axis=1)
    return tf.scatter_nd(indices=indices, updates=tiled, shape=[dim, dim])
```

Result:

```
tf.Session().run(circulant([1,2,3,4,5,6]))

array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]], dtype=int32)
```